# How to apply the conditional replacement on all columns of DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can I apply the conditional replacement on all columns of DataFrame `df` in Spark using Scala?

```
df.withColumn("make", when(col("make").equalTo("true"), 1).otherwise(0)
```

Comment: The same condition (`equalTo("Tesla")`) to all the columns in the dataframe you mean?

Comment: @philantrovert Yes, the same condition applied to all the columns of the DataFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` over `df.columns` and generate your expression:

```
val expression =  df1.columns
                     .map{c => when(col(c).equalTo("Tesla") , "S").otherwise("DDD").as(c) }
```

And then `select` it:

```
df1.select(expression : _* ).show(false)
```